# Elegant solution to retrieve custom date and time?

Tags: android

I am currently using a date and time picker to retrieve a user-submitted date and time, and then I set a control's text to the date and time selected.

I am using the following code:

```
new DatePickerDialog(newlog3.this, d, calDT.get(Calendar.YEAR), calDT.get(Calendar.MONTH), calDT.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();

new TimePickerDialog(newlog3.this, t, calDT.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), calDT.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true).show();

optCustom.setText(fmtDT.format(calDT.getTime()));
```

Now, while the above code block does bring up the date and time widgets and sets the text, the code block is being executed in full before the user can select the date.. ie: It brings up the date box first, then the time box over that, and then updates the text, all without any user interaction. I would like the date widget to wait to execute the time selector until the date selection is done, and i would like the settext to execute only after the time widget is done.

How is this possible? Or is there is a more elegant solution that is escaping me?

Edit: This is the code for DatePickerDialog/TimePickerDialog which is located within the class:

```
 DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() { 
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, 
                    int dayOfMonth) { 
            calDT.set(Calendar.YEAR, year); 
            calDT.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear); 
            calDT.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth); 
          //updateLabel(); 
        } 
      };   
 TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener t=new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() { 
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, 
                             int minute) { 
            calDT.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay); 
            calDT.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute); 
          //updateLabel(); 
        } 
      };
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen when *DatePickerDialog* closes with [DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener.html). When onDateSet(...) is called show the next dialog (TimePickerDialog).

Edit: I've pasted code which you asked

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {    

private final Calendar selectedDate = Calendar.getInstance();

final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() { 
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,  int dayOfMonth) { 
            selectedDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            selectedDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            selectedDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            new TimePickerDialog(YourActivity.this, timeListener, 0, 0, true).show();
        } 
      };   

final TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() { 
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,  int minute) { 
            selectedDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            selectedDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);              
            // push flow to the next step
        } 
      }; 

public void startTimeWizard() {
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());       
    new DatePickerDialog(this, dateListener, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();    
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    startTimeWizard();
}
```

}

Comment: do you think you could give a code sample? i'm currently using the above listeners in my class, but how would i adapt them to watch for dialog closing?

Comment: thanks again.. i figured it out based on your first suggestion and had the same code on my end but my settext wasn't updating (or so i thought.. i had the textview set to invisible).. anyway.. it's working now. just noticed you didn't set current hour/minute on the timedialog.. :p